# show toggle button on user generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying without success to add a toggle button to a user generated input. this is a font awesome toggle button.

here is my pen: http://codepen.io/lucky500/pen/bdpzbd and the code.

```
        <div id="list" class="greatList clearfix" >
        <ul class="greatList" style='display: none;'>
            <li class="items">
                <div class="box">
                    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x active" id="on"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x fa-rotate-180 inactive" id="off" style='display: none;'></i>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //toggler

    $('.box').click(function() {
        $('.inactive, .active').toggle();
    });


    var trash = '<span class="delete">X</span>';
    var toggleButton = '<div class="box"></div>';


    //To allow the user to use enter
$('#addButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $('#addItems').val();
    var placeIt = $('<li style="display: block;">' + toggleButton + item +  trash + '</li>');

    if(!$.trim($('#addItems').val())) {
        alert('Please enter text to add to the list');
    } else {
        $('.greatList').append(placeIt);

    };
})

//To remove li when .trash is clicked
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').fadeOut(350);
});
```

});

all the help is appreciated!

Comment: the toggle button is being added in your code pen... you just need to style it so you can see it. and remove the negative margin so its still in view.

Comment: I tried that Will, but it did not work. Thanks anyways

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your problem. What's happening?

Comment: Hey Will, I actually solved the problem after messing around with the code a bit... I added the <i> tag with my toggle inside my variable! Thanks again!

Comment: var toggleButton = '<div class="box" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x active" id="on"></i></div>';

Answer (score 1):

I actually just had to add the i tag with my toggle inside my toggleButton var... now onto trying to get my toggle to work!

```
var toggleButton = '<div class="box" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x active" id="on"></i></div>';
```